# What does a chain usually mean in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I've been studying a little bit about rings and modules. Chains, particularly chains of ideals, appear somewhat frequently.

I'm a little confused about what exactly a chain is since it is usually presented as back-to-back inequalities with an ellipsis.

**What is the most frequent meaning of chain in abstract algebra? Is there ever a need to simultaneously talk about more than one kind of chain-like entity?**

In set theory, I'm pretty sure a chain $C$ is a subset of $2^X$, where $X$ is a fixed set, that is linearly-ordered by inclusion, i.e. it holds that for all $a$ and $b$ in $C$ that $a \subset b$ or $b \subset a$. This first kind of chain can, I think, also be though of as a monotonic "sequence" indexed with an ordered set $I$ of the same order type as $(X, \subset)$.

Most of the time, though, it doesn't seem like we need this much generality. When I see a chain written down, it appears to be just a finite or countably infinite monotonic sequence like the following.

$$ a_1 \le a_2 \le \cdots \;\;\text{or}\;\; b_1 \ge b_2 \ge \cdots $$

The second definition is more restrictive than the first, and it forces us to only consider chains that are both countable and have either a maximum or minimum element.

The reason I was confused is, for example, the union of a chain (first definition) of ideals is also an ideal. If $a$ is in $\cup C$, then $a$ is in some element $A$ of $C$ and thus $ra \in A \subset \cup C$. If $a$ and $b$ are in $\cup C$, then $a$ is in some element $A$ and $B$ is in some element $B$. Assume without loss of generality that $A \subset B$, so $a$ and $b$ are both in $B$ and thus $a+b$ is in $B$ as well and thus in $C$.

Using this kind of chain feels like we're making a stronger statement than using the sequence kind of chain, but maybe it suffices to use the more restrictive kind in an abstract algebra setting for a reason I can't see.

Comment: I believe the ascending chain condition is the most common context for algebraic chains. Noetherian and Artinian rings/modules are such examples.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition

Comment: In order theory, a chain of a poset is a linearly ordered subset. This definition encompasses every definition you mention.

Comment: @Greg Nisbet - It seems you pretty much have the idea of what a chain is. For ideals, it is, for example,  a collection of ideals linearly ordered by inclusion. Some authors use the $\leq$ notation in this situation, others prefer $\subseteq.$ In any event, check the wiki article mentioned in another comment.

Comment: I'd like to mention that there is also a common but completely unrelated use of the word "chain" in algebra, in the context of homology.

Comment: A chain in a poset is a subset that is linearly ordered (any two elements are comparable $a\le b$ or $b\le a)$ by the induced order on the subset. That's the most frequent denotation in my experience.